# How to read Outlook addressbook in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I am developing an application which will read Addressbook of Outlook as well as Thunderbird.
Anybody knows how to read the contact information from .pst files. I am using PowerBuilder 11.5 Classical and Windows 7 32Bit With Outlook 2007 & Thunderbird 24.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I checked, the PST file format wasn't documented sufficiently to read directly, so you'd have to do OLE into Outlook ([lots](http://downloads.sybase.com/codexchange/powerbuilder/404/PowerBuilder_-_Controlling_the_Outlook_session_using_OLE.htm) of [examples](http://anvil-of-time.com/wordpress/powerbuilder/powerbuilder-reading-outlook-items/) on [how](http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_outlook.html) to do [this](https://brucearmstrong.sys-con.com/node/170833/mobile)). Last time I looked, Thunderbird had no OLE, but you could use the FileRead(), etc... file access functionality in PowerBuilder to read the file using the [file format specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%28file_format%29) (caveat: I've not done this for Thunderbird, so I have no idea how easy or hard it is).

Good luck,

Terry